# How do i group a table on a client and retreive the first admit in current year without having a null in prior discharge dates?

Tags: db2, dbeaver

I have a table that contains client information with Episodes of treatment, admissions and discharges for each separate episode of treatment.

```
Client    Episode    Admission_date    Discharge_date
   x         1         05-06-2020           Null
   x         2         09-26-2020        12-30-2020
   x         3         01-03-2021        In Process
   y         1         03-02-2020        05-20-2020
   y         2         08-13-2020        11-23-2020
   y         3         02-01-2021        03-31-2021
   y         4         04-02-2021        In Process
```

I want to retrieve clients Y Episode 3(just retrieve the client no need episode) because its the first admission in year 2021 1st Qtr and their previous discharge date is less than(has to be less) Episode 3's admission date. But i dont want to retreive x even though their current admission date is less than previous discharge date because their first episode has a null in discharge which means they are still active. Need inactive clients only.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you

Desired result:
Client    Episode    Admission_date    Discharge_date
y         3         02-01-2021        03-31-2021

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your table definition (SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename) and your desired result set from the sample data you showed us.  And notice this: if you use CHAR or VARCHAR() columns to hold dates, your problem becomes unreasonably difficult. Use DATE columns.

Comment: db2 and mysql are two different database products. Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you are actually using.

Comment: The admission and discharge dates are datetime field. client ID and episode number are int. I said in process for discharge date so you dont get confused with null but they are actually null too since they're on going

Comment: @Shadow DBeaver accepts both the syntax but db2 would be preferrable

Comment: Dbeaver may accept both syntaxes, but your database will not.

Comment: Do you want to get records with "year 2021 1st Qtr" only and hardcode these constants in the query? What if you have multiple "year 2021 1st Qtr" records for some client, and the 1-st such a record has previous discharge date not less than current admission date? Do you want to check, if the next record may be returned or just skip this client at all?